# How can I modify the code to avoid SQL-injection attack?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-injection

I need to implement a fuzzy search for two fields, `businessName` and `businessAddress`. Both of them can be `null`. If one field is `null`, search should be based on the other field.

To be specific,

- if `businessName="name"` and `businessAddress="address"` then execute `select * from business where businessName like '%name%' and businessAddress like '%address%'`
- if `businessName=null` and `businessAddress="address"` then execute `select * from business where businessAddress like '%address%'`
- if `businessName=null` and `businessAddress=null` then execute `select * from business`

My code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select * from business where 1=1 ");

if (businessName != null) {
    sb.append("and businessName like '%" + businessName + "%' ");
}
if (businessAddress != null) {
    sb.append("and businessAddress like '%" + businessAddress + "%' ");
}

try {
    con = DBUtil.getConnection();
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
} ...
```

Apparently it's in danger of SQL-injection attack. I know method `prepareStatement.setString()` can avoid attack, but number of fields is uncertain before verification.

How can I modify it? Separate method for each case or code like below seem ugly.

```
if(businessName!=null){
    if(businessAddress!=null){
        sql = ...;
    }else {
        sql = ...;
    }
else{
...
```

Comment: "I know method prepareStatement.setString() can avoid attack,but number of fields is uncertain before verification." <- it just 4 different cases in your example not hundreds of combinations. Checking which passed values are null and preparing 3 different prepared statements and then setting the parameter with the appropriate method really isn't much code or hassle.

Comment: if the fields are maybe empty but are known at compile time, you can add all of them to your query and test for „input = column or input is missing“

Comment: [This is for PHP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where) but you can get the idea. Collect parameters into array and then loop over this array doing smth like pst.setStr(i,param); Also there is an SQL based solution but you have to send each parameter twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, ever, concatenate values into a query string like that. Always use prepared statements with parameters when executing queries, especially with user-sourced values.

A simple solution for your case is to use a list of values for each parameter you add, and then set the values collected for those parameters before execute:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select * from business where 1=1 ");
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
if (businessName != null) {
    sb.append("and businessName like '%' || ? || '%' ");
    parameters.add(businessName);
}
if (businessAddress != null) {
    sb.append("and businessAddress like '%' || ? || '%' ");
    parameters.add(businessAddress)
}

try (Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sb.toString())) {
    int index = 1;
    for (String parameter : parameters) {
        pst.setString(index++, parameter);
    }
    
    try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have parameters of varying types, use a `List<Object>` and `setObject` instead.

---

The solution in the [answer by MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73456026/466862) also works, but not all database systems optimize that type of query well (especially if you have a lot of such conditions), which might affect performance. For only a few conditions, the solution by MT0 is more readable, while having same/similar performance.

Comment: Hi Mark, is there a difference between `'%' || ? || '%'` and adding the wildcards into the variable, then simply using `?`. I've never used (or seen) the _concatenators_ `||` before ...

Comment: @Eric `||` is the SQL standard concatenation operator (some SQL dialects use `+`, or require you to use a function like `CONCAT`), it is equivalent to Java `"%" + someVariable + "%"`. So, yes, you could use a bare `?` and perform the concatenation in your Java code.

Comment: Thanks, I was just a little unsure if there was some _hidden_ technical reason for not adding the wildcards Java side.

Comment: @Eric This is primarily opinion/taste

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dynamic SQL and can use bind variables in the query:

```java
String query = "select * from business where businessName LIKE '%' || ? || '%' AND businessAddress LIKE '%' || ? || '%'";
```

*(Assuming `||` is the string concatenation operator for your SQL dialect.)*

And then use a prepared statement and bind `businessName` and `businessAddress` to the variables.

```java
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1,businessName);
st.setString(2,businessAddress);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

*(Add exception handling.)*

---

Or, if your SQL dialect requires you to handle `NULL` separately from the `LIKE` then :

```java
String query = "select * from business
                where (:name IS NULL OR businessName LIKE '%' || :name || '%')
                AND   (:addr IS NULL OR businessAddress LIKE '%' || :addr || '%')";
```

and use named bind variables `:name` and `:addr` (or use `?` pass the values twice).

Comment: This doesn't address the problem the OP describes of creating a dynamic query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There is no need to use a dynamic query. `'%' || NULL || '%'` will be evaluated as `'%%'` and match all strings.

Comment: In most SQL dialects (those following the SQL standard), `'%' || NULL || '%'` will evaluate to `NULL`, making the like expression evaluate to `UNKNOWN`, causing the entire where condition to evaluate to `FALSE`. You're likely thinking of Oracle, where `NULL` is equivalent to empty string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You still do not need to use dynamic SQL as you can use `WHERE (:name IS NULL OR businessName LIKE '%' || :name || '%') ...`

Comment: True, but it doesn't always result in well-performing queries.

Answer (score 0):

Except Mark Rotteveel's answer, I think there are additional methods to solve your question.

<del>1.Escape user's input string to avoid sql-injection.**But this way is not 100% secure**.You can use ESAPI to do this, please refer to [SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-4-escaping-all-user-supplied-input).</del>

2.You can use ORM framework,like MyBatis. For example, MyBatis have [dynamic-sql](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html),it allows you generate different sql according to different conditions. In addition, use `#{xxx}` not `${xxx}` to keep sql-injection away.

Comment: Why would you recommend a method which is not 100% secure?

Comment: @Your Common Sense  Because in some restricted scenarios, like old code or development time is tight, more secure(although is not 100% ) is also make more sense.